# SSAS: new customers list mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to get the list of new customers of the current period, so I tried to create a dynamic named Set that I will pass as  filter, so I created a calculated Measure that returns all previous sales of the current period (dynamic):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Previous Period sales]  AS
SUM(NULL:[Dim Date].[Main Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER,[Measures].[Qty Sold]),
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Qty Sold] }

And then filter by this measure to get the list of 'old customers':

CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[Old Customers]
 AS Filter([Dim Customer].[Customer Key].[Customer Key].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Previous Period sales]<>0 ) ;
```

The Idea is to get the difference between all customers and the 'old customers' so that I get the active customers of the selected period.

But when I first test the 'old customers' set, I get no results !!

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try removing the Non_Empty_Behavior

Comment: Didn't know previously, but I think that's the problem.  Good outline of the danger of NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOUR here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/03/11/the-dangers-of-non_empty_behavior/

Comment: Thanks all, but the non empty behavior does not make any change !